# iOS Unity3D game with Apple Watch companion

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, apple-watch

guys.

**First goes the questions.**

I need to combine different Xcode projects for iOS and watchOS. And I need automation for this.

1. Is it possible to set reference in iOS-Xcode project to watchOS-Xcode project, and setup outer project to build target iOS app with embedded watchOS app, by using targets of inner project? Is it possible to do such a thing with workspaces?
2. Are there exist some command line tools for managing Xcode project, like adding targets, changing build settings, setup build phases, add resources and so on?

**Problem summary.**

I'm currently developing video game with Unity3D for iOS and want to make a companion application for watchOS. The problem is that Unity doesn't have any built-in support for watchOS, thus I have to care about integration of watchOS part by myself.

I have Unity project for the game itself and different Xcode project for watchOS part of the game. Now I combine Unity-generated Xcode project with the necessary parts of watchOS project manually: I create WatchKit App target, then import necessary resources from the separate watchOS-project, setup build settings as required - and that do the thing, I get the game with Apple Watch support.

The thing is, that I need to do automation for this process. But I haven't found some useful information on this topic neither here (on stackoverflow), not did on official apple developers' site, not on unityanswers.com, nor in Xcode documentation.

Thanks in advance.